# Scrolling news feed overlaps divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm wanting to add a scrolling news feed to a small app I have built, however all the scripts or plugins I have seen so far have been for horizontal scrolling - whereas I'm wanting to scroll vertically.

I came across a question with this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/rNXs9/1/, which would work well for me. I would load each news item in to a div and then have it scroll.

I tried to implement this, but the DIVs overlap and become unreadable. See my fiddle here, https://jsfiddle.net/wgyxo8gv/.

I'm not very proficient with JS or CSS and so I'm not too sure what is causing this to happen and therefore how to fix it.

Here is the JS that is scrolling the items:

```
window.verticalScroller = function($elem) {
    var top = parseInt($elem.css("top"));
    var temp = -1 * $('#verticalScroller > div').height();
    if(top < temp) {
        top = $('#verticalScroller').height()
        $elem.css("top", top);
    }
    $elem.animate({ top: (parseInt(top)-60) }, 600, function () {
      window.verticalScroller($(this))
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $("#verticalScroller > div").each(function () {
          $(this).css("top", i);
          i += 60;
          window.verticalScroller($(this));
    });
});
```

And the CSS for each DIV:

```
#verticalScroller {
    position: absolute;
    width:400px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#verticalScroller > div{
    position:absolute;
    width:380px;
    padding-left:10px;
    height:auto;
    border: dotted white;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

If anyone can point out how I can just get the divs to scroll one after the other without overlapping that would be great. Or if there is a plugin out there that works vertically rather than horizontally that works then that could work too - all my searches for vertical scrolling return endless pagination scripts.

Comment: Your problem is your script is for divs with a static height and you have divs with dynamic height.

Comment: @smdsgn How would I alter the script to deal with dynamic heights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this by approaching this from a slightly different angle.

Instead of using divs, I used a list with the default styling removed and created a ticker function that just slid the list items up one every 5 seconds - the effect isn't quite continuous scrolling but it slides a news item up, pauses for it to be read and then continues on:

```
function tick(){
    $('#ticker li:first').slideUp( function ()
    (this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown(); });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function(){ tick() }, 5000);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgyxo8gv/6/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are already looking in adapt your first code you can do it this way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  var i = 0;
  var totalHeight = 0;
  $("#verticalScroller > div").each(function () {
     $(this).css("top", i);
     i += $(this).height();
     totalHeight = totalHeight + $(this).height();
  });
  
  var loop = setInterval(function(){ verticalScroller() }, 2000);
  
  var index = 0;
  function verticalScroller() {
     var $currentChild = $("#verticalScroller > div").eq(index);
     var scroll = $currentChild.height();
    
     $("#verticalScroller > div").animate({ top: "-="+scroll }, 600, function() {
        var top = totalHeight - $currentChild.height();
     $currentChild.css({ top : top});
     });
    
     if(index == $("#verticalScroller > div").length-1) index = 0;
     else index++;
  }
  
});
```

```css
#verticalScroller {
    position: absolute;
    width:400px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: silver;
}

#verticalScroller > div{
    position:absolute;
    width:380px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height:auto;
    border-bottom: dotted white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="verticalScroller">
<div>
Nude cyclist Nick Lowe identified as mystery rider in leopard G-string
<br>
A nude cyclist who caused a thong and dance in Marlborough has been exposed &acirc;&#128;&#147; he&#039;s Lower Hutt naturist Nick Lowe.
</div>
<div>
Josh Hazlewood pleads guilty to dissent after appeal rejected
<br>
Australian pace bowler Josh Hazlewood has pleaded guilty to dissent after reacting angrily when Black Cap Kane Williamson survived a contentious appeal and DRS review in the second test at Hagley Oval.
</div>
<div>
Firefighters attending increasing number of non-fire related and bizarre callouts
<br>
Rescuing ducklings stuck in drains, requests to fill water tanks and helping fellow firefighters&#039; pet cockatoos - it&#039;s all part of the job for the fire service these days.
</div>
<div>
Mike Hosking gives his two cents on parenting
<br>
Mike Hosking thinks Kiwi teenagers have an &quot;inflated sense of entitlement.&quot;
</div>
<div>
Australia cruising towards series victory after Black Caps&#039; fight not enough
<br>
It&#039;s free entry at Hagley Oval and sadly too familiar for New Zealand against Australia on the final day of the test cricket summer.
</div>
<div>
Big fire strikes near Melbourne
<br>
A major bushfire is burning in the Melbourne area, with emergency services telling some residents it&#039;s too late to flee.
</div>
<div>
Smalltown GP offers $400k job and a slice of the business after struggling to recruit
<br>
A smalltown rural GP in the North Island is offering $400,000 to a junior doctor after a fruitless two-year search for staff.
</div>
<div>
Auckland Zoo&#039;s baby red pandas give warm fuzzies at weigh-in
<br>
Baby red panda twins at Auckland Zoo in Western Springs have had their first weigh-in and are cuter than ever.
</div>
<div>
Max Key reads ruthless messages directed at him
<br>
Max Key read out a list of mean social media posts with a smile on his face, even though he was the butt of every joke.
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var i = 0;

$("#verticalScroller > div").each(function () {
      $(this).css("top", i);
      i += $(this).height(); // CHANGE THIS
      window.verticalScroller($(this));
  });
});
```

Result: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wgyxo8gv/3/)

When you set top for each div, you do not know the distance of each one of them from the top, because they have not fixed height. To set a correct top, you have to consider the real height of each div, that is why you have to change the line to `i += $(this).height();`.

If you want, you can add an addictional fixed amount of pixel to add some white space between the divs: `i += $(this).height() + 10;`.

Comment: Oh cool - that works for the height, but if you animate the scrolling again they still overlap - this is the updated fiddle with your changes https://jsfiddle.net/wgyxo8gv/5/